# Non strictly singular operators

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, banach-spaces

Let $X$ be a separable Banach space and let $T:X\to X$ be a bounded operator that is **not** strictly singular. Can we always find an infinite dimensional, closed, **and complemented** subspace $Y$ of $X$ such that $T:Y\to T(Y)$ is an isomorphism?

I cannot show this is true, and I cannot think of a counterexample. The only idea of counterexample I had was looking at HI spaces, where every operator is of the form $\lambda I+S$, where $S$ is strictly singular. However, as far as I know, such operators (when $\lambda\neq 0$) are isomorphisms on a closed, finite-codimensional subspace, thus complemented.

Answer (score 1):

This was answered in the negative in [this post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/212316/non-strictly-singular-operators-and-complemented-subspaces) at MathOverflow.

See the first answer there and Bill Johnson's comment to the second answer.